# Run-time Error 1004 after copying more than 5 sheets data

Tags: vba, excel

I have written code to copy data from different sheets located in separate workbooks to a new master sheet, everything is working fine except whenever the number of workbooks increase from 5 in the folder I get this error `Run-time Error 1004` and then importing stops. here is the code:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\hnoorzai\Desktop\test\")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

        'Change B3:H to the range your working on and also B in B65536 to any column required.
        bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("B3:H350" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

        'Below only change "B" column name to your required column name
        Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        bookList.Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank for the help in advance :)

Comment: is it allays happening with the same workbook ? try for debugging moving the workbook with the error to another folder, and see if it happens with the next one in the que ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I did move to another folder and tried many other techniques but still I get the same error any other clue please ???

Comment: I don't know if this will help but you should try qualifying all of your ranges. So whereever it just says `Range...` change it to `bookList.Worksheets(1).Range...` or whatever the correct worksheet and book is.

Comment: This should not work,   `sh.Range("B3:H350" & sh.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row)`

Comment: @Davesexcel, good point! Interestingly it will just add digits to the end, giving an address like `B3:H350123`. Instead it should be `sh.Range("B3:H" & sh.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row)`, I assume.

Comment: @Davesexcel but it is working actually I changed my code from B3:H to B3:H350 so it should copy from starting B3 to H350 :)

Comment: @Davesexcel thank you, your trick did the Job ;)

Comment: This might be a bit obvious, but sometimes the obvious things are the things we don't check - is the 6th file in the folder actually a valid Excel workbook?  If not, it probably won't get past the Workbooks.Open method.  By the way, which line of code causes the crash?

Comment: @YowE3K thank you, the problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure it is a qualifying issue, dim and set your worksheets and ranges accordingly.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim bookList As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, rw As Long
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\TextCSV\")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each everyObj In filesObj

        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
        Set sh = bookList.Sheets(1)

        With sh
            rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng = .Range("B3:H" & rw)
        End With

        'Change B3:H to the range your working on and also B in B65536 to any column required.
        rng.Copy

        With wb
            .Sheets(1).Cells(.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

        bookList.Close

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid Activating any workbooks and transfer the values as an array.

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
    Dim rSource As Range, Target As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'change folder path of excel files here
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\hnoorzai\Desktop\test\")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
       .
        Set rSource = bookList.Worksheets(1).Range("B3:H350" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row)

        Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        Target.Resize(rSource.Rows.Count, rSource.Columns.Count).Value = rSource.Value

        bookList.Close
    Next
End Sub
```